# Event listeners and closures on HTML collection in for loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop, closures, htmlcollection

The code is

```
//Logic which works when the desired element is clicked
function changeArtistPhotoAndBio(prop) {
    var artistPhoto = document.getElementsByClassName("artist-photo")[0];
    var artistBio = document.getElementsByClassName("artist-bio")[0];

    var i = prop.getAttribute("src").indexOf(".jpg");
    var photoName = prop.getAttribute("src").slice (0, i);

    artistPhoto.style.background="url(" + photoName + "-large.jpg";
    console.log("it happened");
};

//Setting listeners for the click event in the loop
var artists = document.getElementsByClassName("gallery")[0].getElementsByTagName("img");
for (var i = 0; i < artists.length; i++) {
    artists[i].addEventListener("click", changeArtistPhotoAndBio(artists[i]));
}
```

And the console output is

```
7x it happened
```

And the event handler for the click function does not work. I've tried isolating handler in the closure, like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < artists.length; i++) {(function(i) {
    artists[i].addEventListener("click", changeArtistPhotoAndBio(artists[i]));
}(i))
}
```

but the output is still the same. So there are two questions:

1) Why does the console output contain results of seven handler invocations if I did not invoke the function, just set it as a handler?

2) How can I set handlers in the "for" loop for HTML collection?

Comment: It should be e.g `changeArtistPhotoAndBio.bind({}, artists[i])` and you are missing closing parenthensis here: `"url(" + photoName + "-large.jpg";`

Comment: Thanks for the answer and for noting the parenthesis. However I've already tried to bind the function and to no avail (i.e. the handler does not work). Of course, I've tried your example and it still does not work.

Comment: You mean the handler isn't fired? You should provide minimalistic sample replicating your issue, e.g on jsFiddle

Comment: Okay, here is the fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/snc8cL5y/2/

I've tested through it and for whatever reason it does not work when I look up the "img" elements, but does work with the lookup for "li" elements.

Comment: But what do you mean by `it does not work`? In your jsfiddle, if i click image, the click handler is called

Comment: So in your case the alert is visible?

Here is the updated version of the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/snc8cL5y/3/

When I click on the image and I have `.getElementsByTagName("img");` the handler does not work. If I change it to `.getElementsByTagName("li");` however, the handler does work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103949/discussion-between-dronich-and-a-wolff).

Comment: Ya, alert is displayed if i click image, just like what ti is expected regarding your code. So i still don't see what is your issue

Comment: Yep, you're right, everything works, thank you!

But I still don't understand why there were 7 invocations of the handler in my code if I did not call it. Could you, please, possibly dwell on it?

Comment: Becasue using `artists[i].addEventListener("click", changeArtistPhotoAndBio(artists[i]));` you are using as handler result of what return function `changeArtistPhotoAndBio` which in your case is `undefined` (this function return nothing). If you want to use the function itself as handler, you have to use reference of it or you could wrap it in anonymous function. Basically, using `anyFunction()` calls the function `anyFunction`

Answer (score 0):

You have to use **closures**:

```
var artists = document.getElementsByClassName("gallery")[0].getElementsByTagName("img");
for (var i = 0; i < artists.length; i++) {
    artists[i].addEventListener("click", function(index) {
        return function() {
            //You can use index for the current clicked item index
            // console.log(index);
            var artistPhoto = document.getElementsByClassName("artist-photo")[0];
            var artistBio = document.getElementsByClassName("artist-bio")[0];

            var i = this.getAttribute("src").indexOf(".jpg");
            var photoName = this.getAttribute("src").slice (0, i);

            artistPhoto.style.background="url(" + photoName + "-large.jpg";
            console.log("it happened");

        }
    }(i));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('body *').on('mouseover',function(){console.log(this.tagName)});
```

`$('body *')` selects all elements within the body.